# Differentiability and absolute value function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a differentiable function such that $f(0)=0$. Give the neccessary and sufficient condition for $g(x)=|f(x)|$ to be differentiable at $x=0$.

The answer is obvious $f'(0)=0$. Infact $f'(0)=0 \Rightarrow |f| $ is differentiable at $x=0$ is obvious since given $\epsilon>0$, $\forall x_n\rightarrow 0 $ with $x_n \neq 0 \; \forall n\in \Bbb N\;$ $$ \lim \frac{f(x_n)}{x_n}=0 \Rightarrow |\frac{f(x_n)}{x_n}|<\epsilon\; (e.v) \Rightarrow |\frac{|f(x_n)|}{x_n}|<\epsilon\; (e.v) \Rightarrow \lim \frac{|f(x_n)|}{x_n}=0 $$ $$\Rightarrow\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{|f(h)|}{h}=0$$ i.e $|f|'(0)=0$ i.e  $|f|$ is differentiable at $x=0$.

How to show $|f|$ is diffferentiable at $x=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $f'(0)=0$ ??

Answer (score 1):

Got it!!!

If $|f|$ is differentiable at $x=0$ then since $|f(x)|\ge 0\, \forall x\in \Bbb R$ and $f(0)=0$ , then $x=0$ is the minimum of $|f|$, i.e $|f|'(0)=0$ then $\lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{|f(h)|}{h}=0$ , i.e $$\forall x_n\rightarrow0 , x_n\neq0\; \forall n\in \Bbb N\; \lim \frac{|f(x_n)|}{x_n}=0,$$ i.e given $\epsilon>0$ $$|\frac{|f(x_n)|}{x_n}|<\epsilon \; (e.v)\Rightarrow |\frac{f(x_n)}{x_n}|<\epsilon\; (e.v) \Rightarrow \lim \frac{f(x_n)}{x_n}=0$$ $$\Rightarrow\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(h)}{h}=0$$ i.e $f'(0)=0.$

Comment: Other solutions are welcome